# Draw Polygons by Longitude/Latitude

Tags: c#, dotspatial

I am getting sql spatial results from my database query that consists of long/lat polygons.

I am using these results in my c# windows form application.

How can I draw each polygon from their long/lat points in my windows form application?

I want each drawn polygon to be selectable, so that when a user clicks on the shape an event will be raised to perform some task in the code behind.

I used an open source library dotspatial to add a map control on my windows form and adding a world shapefile to show the location of the polygons that will be drawn, but I can't find a way that how can I add a layer to the dotspatial map control to draw polygons.

Is there any other way that I can accomplish this task?

This is a windows desktop standalone application with no internet connectivity.

Comment: I notice that you have not yet taken the 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce new users to this site and its protocols.